# What are the benefits of using .css over .php with content-type: text/css?

Tags: php, css

What are the benefits of using a CSS external stylesheet over a php file set to `content-type: text/css`? If you place this header at the top of a PHP file I feel like you have so much more potential:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");

    if($query_string = "contact_us") {
        #nav {}
    }
?>
```

(^ that's a .php file). http://shapeshed.com/using_php_to_enhance_css/

If there are no downfalls (and I checked how they were cached in Chrome's Network Panel and I believe it's the same), isn't it kind of like whether to use `.html` or `.php`?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some differences:

- PHP will create extra CPU / memory overhead compared with serving purely static CSS. Probably not all that much, but still a consideration. The more processing you do the bigger a deal it is, obviously.
- You can't push PHP files to a CDN
- SASS and LESS have been developed to deal with any dynamic features you might need so PHP isn't likely necessary
- Sounds like you're worried about serving more CSS than is needed for certain pages. Realistically it's not an issue since browsers will cache the CSS after the first download.

Additional thoughts:

I wrote a UI template engine that isolates both JS and CSS code to only the specific views on which they are used. If a CSS or JS is used more than once, it is pushed to the "kitchen sink level" and included globally. This limits selector conflicts and also best balances the number of HTTP requests and total download size per request. Also keeping relevant code (i.e. button event listeners or page / element-specific styles) close together helps with more rapid programming, especially for non-expert teams / developers.

Comment: thanks :D you have convinced me! I am going to go learn SASS now.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't send a customized style sheet for each page, but if the entire site has no use for *the kitchen sink*, then there's no reason to send it.  Great list otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

That could have been nice before CSS preprocessors such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: I looked at the tutorial for nesting, and that's look very good. Wouldn't it be kind of a pain to have to load all the SASS files though?

Comment: You'll use [watchers](http://livereload.com/) to recompile files on changes, then deploy the whole thing to a big minified CSS to reduce payload. This way you develop in a more comfortable way by using different files [you can reuse], taking advantage of partials, polyfills, and other goodies.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic CSS isn't even as useful as dynamic JavaScript, much less dynamic HTML. Having one large file with all the rules in it is more effective than having a file with rules that change since you can more easily cache the former in the client than the latter.

Comment: By "one large file" you mean combining all your stylesheets?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could stick to one static file per URL regardless of what CSS classes may be used in it, although sharing a stylesheet among many URLs would likely be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that there isn't much benefit to this...dynamic CSS doesn't have many valid use-cases, and the one you're describing certainly isn't one of them. If you just combine and minify all of your css into a single file, it'll cache on the client and be downloaded only when you bust the cache it.

Comment: but I have a site with 2 different layouts and I don't want to stick a #contact_us in the body tag and have to use it ahead of all my CSS statements. I guess 2 CSS files, I thought this content-type was my savior.

Answer (score 0):

In a modular CMS, this could be useful. As long as your application could generate a `.php` URL that consistently generates the exact same CSS for caching purposes, you could dramatically reduce the amount of CSS to download. For example, pages that uses 1 theme and 5 modules (each providing CSS) could return the CSS for that combination, instead of the CSS for 1 theme and 50 modules. That could be the difference between 50KB of CSS and 500KB -- a huge savings for slower connections.

If your website is hand-made, as in a website that has specific goals known ahead of time, then there's really not a good reason to do this as others have answered.

Comment: Who has CSS files that are that big?  Even 50KB is outrageous for a production site, to suggest that anyone has 500KB is insanity.

Comment: @cimmanon It's very common, and I was explaining a modular CMS tends to compound the problem even more. I just loaded up facebook.com and found it's CSS is 58 KB compressed, 356 KB uncompressed. Twitter.com is 62 KB compressed, 287 KB uncompressed. Are yours smaller than that in your production sites?

Comment: None of my production sites have a combined uncompressed size over 50KB (that's throwing in IE only styles as well).  My current project is hovering around 30KB compressed.  Twitter and Facebook are not exactly good role models.

Comment: Fair enough. I only picked those because they have a real need to keep the CSS size down. But I'm sure a more focused project could keep the size very small, like it sounds like yours do.